# mkdir: cannot create directory ‘test’: Read-only file system - WSL2

Tags: 18.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I tried to create a file it says

> mkdir: cannot create directory ‘test’: Read-only file system

I'm in windows fast ring programme. I have recently updated to 19546 build, then this issue persists. I tried remounting the file system and "wsl --shutdown". But none of this solved my problem.

What should i do?

Comment: Assuming the file-system was mounted RW, the only reason it flips to RO is that errors were detected and it was made RO to prevent data-loss. A `fsck` (file system check) is usually the fix; it'll detect errors & correct, then the file-system will mount normally (ie. RW again).   Note: I'm not familiar with WSL.